# TensorFlow - tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, elmo

I tried to update the following [code](https://github.com/JHart96/keras_elmo_embedding_layer/blob/master/elmo.py) from TF 1.7 to TF 1.14 :

```
def build(self, input_shape):
    self.max_length = input_shape[1]
    self.word_mapping = [x[1] for x in sorted(self.idx2word.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])]
    self.lookup_table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_to_string_table_from_tensor(self.word_mapping, default_value="<UNK>")
    self.lookup_table.init.run(session=K.get_session())
    self.elmo_model = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", trainable=self.trainable)
    super(ELMoEmbedding, self).build(input_shape)

def call(self, x):
    x = tf.cast(x, dtype=tf.int64)
    sequence_lengths = tf.cast(tf.count_nonzero(x, axis=1), dtype=tf.int32)
    strings = self.lookup_table.lookup(x)
    inputs = {
        "tokens": strings,
        "sequence_len": sequence_lengths
    }
    return self.elmo_model(inputs, signature="tokens", as_dict=True)[self.output_mode]
```

When I fit my model, the following line

```
self.lookup_table.init.run(session=K.get_session())
```

generates the following error:

> 'StaticHashTableV1' object has no attribute 'init'. So I modified the code following the [TF r1.14 doc](https://tensorflow.google.cn/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup/index_to_string_table_from_tensor?authuser=19&hl=fi)

```
def build(self, input_shape):
    self.max_length = input_shape[1]
    self.word_mapping = [x[1] for x in sorted(self.idx2word.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])]
    #self.lookup_table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_to_string_table_from_tensor(self.word_mapping, default_value="<UNK>")
    self.lookup_table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_to_string_table_from_tensor(self.word_mapping,
            default_value='<UNK>',
            name=None
            )
    with tf.Session() as session:
        session.run(tf.compat.v1.tables_initializer)
    # Initialize the variables (i.e. assign their default value)
    self.elmo_model = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", trainable=self.trainable)
    super(ELMoEmbedding, self).build(input_shape)

def call(self, x):
    x = tf.cast(x, dtype=tf.int64)
    sequence_lengths = tf.cast(tf.count_nonzero(x, axis=1), dtype=tf.int32)
    strings = self.lookup_table.lookup(x)
    inputs = {
        "tokens": strings,
        "sequence_len": sequence_lengths
    }
    return self.elmo_model(inputs, signature="tokens", as_dict=True)[self.output_mode]
```

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 46, in <module>
    protest.train(str(args[0]), dirModel, typeCorpus)
  File "/home/???/clef_2019/protest.py", line 40, in train
    model = classification.runTrain(dataFrame)
  File "/home/???/clef_2019/classification.py", line 97, in runTrain
    model = self.runAlgo(dataFrame, column)
  File "/home/???/clef_2019/classification.py", line 328, in runAlgo
    model.fit(xtrain, y, batch_size=8, epochs = 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kashgari/tasks/base_model.py", line 324, in fit
    **fit_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1433, in fit_generator
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 264, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = batch_function(*batch_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1175, in train_on_batch
    outputs = self.train_function(ins)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3292, in __call__
    run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1458, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable module/bilm/CNN/b_cnn_2 from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/module/bilm/CNN/b_cnn_2/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
     [[{{node el_mo_embedding/module_apply_tokens/bilm/CNN_1/add_2/ReadVariableOp}}]]
```

Thx for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

On

```
with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.compat.v1.tables_initializer)
```

The session stops to exist when you get out of scope. 
You can replace it with

```
tf.compat.v1.tables_initializer().run(session=K.get_session())
```

I think that should do the trick.

Comment: I am getting a slightly different error:

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable module/bilm/CNN/W_cnn_2 from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/module/bilm/CNN/W_cnn_2/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
     [[{{node el_mo_embedding/module_apply_tokens/bilm/CNN/Conv2D_2/ReadVariableOp}}]]`